# How to sort array of dates by days and months in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is anyone know how to filter the array of dates (all in ms) so that as a result, only the dates remain for 1 day or 1 month in Javascript? So in result array must contains only dates day by day or month by month. And if day have few dates different by hours, or min's and etc skip it and save only last one.

For example 2020/11/23 05:00, 2020/11/22 09:15, 2020/11/21 12:30 and etc.

Array looks like [1608362100000,1608361800000,1608361500000,1608274800000,1608188400000,1608102000000,1608015600000,1605423600000,1602745200000,1600153200000,1597474800000,1568530800000]

Comment: Check out https://date-fns.org/

Comment: all those dates in your example are on the same day - are you sure they are in milliseconds and not seconds?

Comment: timestamp you cannot order by day and month but the timestamp always be bigger now than the past day or month.
if you need to order it by max you get the recently to older and min the oposite.

Comment: @Bravo I edit array.

Comment: `[...new Set(yourArrayOfTimestamps.sort((a, b) => a - b).map(n => new Date(n).toDateString()))]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet. Have a look at the different methods on the Date class in case there is another format that suits your needs better.

```js
const dates = [
    1608362100000,
    1608361800000,
    1608361500000,
    1608274800000,
    1608188400000,
    1608102000000,
    1608015600000,
    1605423600000,
    1602745200000,
    1600153200000,
    1597474800000,
    1568530800000,
];

// Sort dates into descending
const descending = dates.sort((a, b) => b - a);

// Create an array or readable date
const datesFormatted = descending.map((val) => new Date(val).toDateString());

// Create a set with the array to leave only unique values
const uniqueDates = new Set(datesFormatted);

// Cast back to an array using spread operator
const results = [...uniqueDates];

// Print results
console.log(results);
```

### EDIT

In regards to your comment about sorting by month. I've made this function. Removing the duplicates for a month specifically won't work here as the Set class is removing duplicate of the `DateString` so try have a go at integrating the Set operation in the correct place to remove the duplicates you would like. I've left you a hint.

This may be a little overwhelming but I implore you to work on understanding each bit of code below down to each bracket. It will up-skill you greatly.

The beauty of this function is that it takes the array of milliseconds, sorts them by whichever date component you would like and returns an array of milliseconds. So you can run sort on it a few times to get the order you would like - i.e sort seconds then months.

```js
/**
 * Sort an array of dates by its components
 * @param {Number[]} datesArr An array of dates (as milliseconds)
 * @param {'ascending'|'descending'} direction Which way to sort the array
 * @param {'seconds'|'days'|'dates'|'months'|'years'} timeComponent Which component to sort by
 */
const sortByDateComponent = (datesArr, direction, timeComponent) => {
    // This will return a number: zero, negative or positive
    const evaluate = (a, b) => (direction === 'ascending' ? a - b : b - a);

    // Run the sort method
    const sortedDates = datesArr.sort((a, b) => {
        const dateA = new Date(a);
        const dateB = new Date(b);

        // What should be done depending on which component is chosen
        const components = {
            seconds: () => evaluate(dateA.getSeconds(), dateB.getSeconds()),
            days: () => evaluate(dateA.getDay(), dateB.getDay()),
            dates: () => evaluate(dateA.getDate(), dateB.getDate()),
            months: () => evaluate(dateA.getMonth(), dateB.getMonth()),
            years: () => evaluate(dateA.getFullYear(), dateB.getFullYear()),
        };

        return components[timeComponent]();
    });
  
  // ================================================
  // This could be a good place to remove duplicates
  // ================================================
  
  return sortedDates
};

// Run our custom sort function on our dates array
const sortedDates = sortByDateComponent(dates, 'descending', 'months');

// Create an array or readable dates
const datesFormatted = sortedDates.map((val) => new Date(val).toDateString());

// Create a set with the array to leave only unique values
const uniqueDates = new Set(datesFormatted);

// Cast back to an array using spread operator
const results = [...uniqueDates];

// Print results
console.log(results);
```

Comment: cool thx u. But what if I need the same actions with array, but sort it by months. I mean contain only unique months.

Comment: I made an edit. Have a go at completing it and let us know if you are still having trouble :)